# Difference between find and GNU find

Tags: find, utilities, gnu

Consider some common *nix systems (say Debian, CentOS, Arch and Kali).

I always used `find`; I don't recall using GNU find, but from [one example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474994/rm-rf-deletes-content-of-current-directory-only-partially/474997#474997) I've seen I assumed the syntax of GNU find might be simpler (though **might** allow less operations).

I have two questions:

1. Is `find` the default "find or-and operate" utility in common systems or will systems come with **both** `find` and `GNU find`?
2. Was `GNU find`**intended** to be simpler to `find`?

Comment: you have **always** used GNU find on linux, unless you're a big user of `find` on busybox or android ;-) On non-linux systems, GNU find is usually named `gfind`.

Comment: Try `find --version` ;)

Comment: Those systems you're referring to  are GNU systems, GNU/Linux for most, though Debian is available for other a few other kernels as well. So it's not surprising that the `find` implementation on those systems is GNU `find`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GNU utilities often implement the POSIX standard, and then also extend it with extra functionality for added convenience (and, as the flip side of that, decreased portability across Unices).  The portability aspect is why you sometime will see answers or comments on this site that are very careful to point out when a GNU utility or some other specific implementation of a utility is assumed.

If you are on a Linux system, you would *very* likely be using the GNU implementation of `find`, and you would probably not have another `find` installed.  On non-Linux systems, you would have a native `find` and the possibility to also install GNU `find` (which would most often install under the name `gfind` or, less often, `gnufind`).

As with most GNU utilities, GNU `find` implements and *extends* [the standard `find` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).  It is therefore not "simpler" but instead arguably more complex in order to be more convenient, and it would be somewhat easier to do certain complex tasks with it than with a strictly standard compliant `find`.

Extended implementations of `find` often, for example, implement the `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` predicates which the standard does not mention, and GNU `find` in particular also has `-printf` to print out the found pathnames using a variety of formatting possibilities (the standard `find` does not have `-printf`), and predicates for doing regular expression matching of various kinds on pathnames, as well as a number of other non-standard predicates, some of which are also found in other implementations of `find` (possibly with ever so slightly different semantics, like `-execdir` which works slightly different depending on what `find` is being used<sup>1</sup>).

The `-delete` predicate, used in the answer that you link to, is non-standard, but implemented by GNU `find` as well as in the `find` on some other non-Linux systems. GNU `find`'s `-delete` will complain if you use it to delete a non-empty directory, but the corresponding option with e.g. OpenBSD's `find` will not (neither will delete the non-empty directory).

Most Linux systems, regardless of distribution, use the same coreutils and findutils toolset (variants like busybox exists, obviously).  To use a completely different set of tool implementations, you would have to move to one of the open source BSD systems or to macOS, Solaris, AIX or some other commercial Unix.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>GNU `find` prepends `./` to pathnames when using `-execdir` while some other implementations don't.</sub>

Comment: And `-print0`, and `-direxec`, and `-delete`, and ... ;-). The null separator options available in GNU tools are particularly convenient.

Comment: @StephenKitt But seldom _needed_ :-)

Comment: right, except when writing non-POSIX answers here ;-). (Or scripts which need to work *anywhere*.)

Comment: The main problem with the GNU documentation is that it tries to let people use non-standard aliases to POSIX methods and thus cause the related scripts to create a vendor lock in.

Comment: @StephenKitt `-print0` is also available on *bsd and solaris; but on solaris `xargs -0` doesn't work, so `gxargs -0` (from `/usr/bin/sfw`) should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

What people often refer to as Linux is better referred to as GNU/Linux: Linux plus GNU. Therefore the tools you are using are probably GNU.

- Linux: a kernel, it is used in GNU/Linux, Android, and many other systems.
- GNU: an operating system, often used with the Linux kernel, but can also be used with BSD, Hurd, Cygwin (a DLL for Microsoft's Windows, it pretends to be a kernel), WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux: GNU without Linux, on Microsoft's Windows), HPUX, Solaris, Dec Athena, and many others.

Therefore you are probably using GNU find.

GNU is a project to re-write, a [Free (free as in freedom, not as in price) version](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) of, all of Unix, including tools such as `find`, the GNU project does not worry about POSIX compliance: It will comply where it makes sense, but will also make improvements.

Also you assumption that there is only one other `find` is wrong.